# A GET request for Google reCaptcha works fine on my local environment but not on my deployed site. Any possibilities why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, recaptcha, grecaptcha

I have deployed a NodeJS web application up onto my DomainRacer hosting server. Everything has been setup and configured properly for the NodeJS application to make a GET request on the root path and render the home page properly.

Within this application, I have an email form in the "Contacts" section. This form contains a Google reCaptcha that I'd like to use for preventative measures against bots.

The way I have configured it, is that once I receive a value from the "g-recaptcha-response", I make a POST request via "fetch()" to my NodeJS backend to a specified path. I take the recaptcha response and save it as a variable, so that I can pass it into the Google site verify API link: [https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=[SECRET_KEY]&response=[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE]](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%5BSECRET_KEY%5D&response=%5BRECAPTCHA_RESPONSE%5D)

This is how it is currently setup in my NodeJS backend (SECRET_KEY and RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE being placeholders):

```
app.post('/contactEmail', async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email,
    recaptcha = req.body.recaptcha,
    site_key = [SECRET_KEY];

    await fetch(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=[SECRET_KEY]&response=[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE]`, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(res => res.json()).then(async (data) => {
        console.log(data['error-codes']);
        if(data.success) {
            var statusCode = await formatEmail(email);
            res.json({statusCode : statusCode});
        } else if(data['error-codes'][0] === 'invalid-input-response') {
            res.json({statusCode: 300});
        } else {
            res.json({statusCode: 400});
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        logError(err)
        res.json({statusCode: 400});
    })
})
```

Here is the script in my EJS file that handles the button click on the form to validate the information before making a POST request to "/contactEmail":

```
<script>
        const form = document.querySelector('#email__form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const recaptcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;

            var emptyInputs = [],
            inputs = [emailForm.querySelector('input'), emailForm.querySelector('textarea')];
            
            inputs.forEach(i => {
                if(i.value.length === 0) {
                    if(!emptyInputs.includes(i)) {
                        emptyInputs.push(i);
                    }
                    i.style.boxShadow = '2px 2px 2px rgb(100, 0, 0)';
                } else {
                    if(emptyInputs.includes(i)) {
                        emptyInputs.pop(i);
                    }
                    i.style.boxShadow = 'none';
                }
            })

            if(emptyInputs.length !== 0) {
                alert('Please fill all fields in the form.');
            } else {
                fetch('/contactEmail', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type':'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({email: inputs[0].value, message: inputs[1].value, recaptcha: recaptcha})
                })
                .then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                    if(data.statusCode === 200) {
                        alert('Form was submitted!')
                        window.location = '/';
                    } else if (data.statusCode === 300) {
                        alert('Please complete reCaptcha');
                    } else {
                        alert('Error submitting form.');
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
```

The issue is that on the deployed site, I never receive a response back from "/contactEmail". However, this exact block of code works perfectly on my local machine. I am able to receive a response on my local machine.

In the deployed website, the POST request indefinitely states that it is "pending".

[/contactEmail POST pending status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZs5T.png)

After a period of time passes, I then receive an internal server error 500 status code.

[/contactEmail POST 500 status code response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adZOu.png)

Things that I have tried:

- attempted to find error logs inside cPanel, but cannot find a place to locate them. I've tried to setup a function to write the errors to a .log file in my backend, but since I never recieve a response from the POST request, nothing gets written to the .log file
- ensured that the domain that I am using is correctly spelled inside the settings of my reCaptcha setup
- tested the POST request in Postman, and received the same behavior from my website
- tried both reCaptcha V2 and reCaptcha V3 to check if there was a compatibility issue
- verified that both the Site Key and Secret Key are correctly spelled inside my code
- asked DomainRacer if there are any restricitions for POST requests and they have stated that there aren't any in place
- made sure that I received a token from the reCaptcha and it was passed along properly on my local environment, which it did

The reason I know the issue lies in the Google site verify URL fetch is because I've tested it by eliminating the fetch() request to the Google site verify link and just returning a temporary status code response. **When I did this, the "/contactEmail" route actually returned a response on my deployed website and redirected back to the homepage.**

I am wondering what the issue with this fetch() request to [https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=[SECRET_KEY]&response=[RECAPTCHA_RESPONSE]](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%5BSECRET_KEY%5D&response=%5BRECAPTCHA_RESPONSE%5D) is?

*I apologize if this question is still vague or not helpful as this is my very first question on this site.*

**UPDATE**

After scouring the internet for hours, I've finally found the issue. Apparently the default **fetch()** is not backend friendly. It seems that I had to install the "isomorphic-fetch" package and use that as a substitute. After replacing the default fetch command with that new package, the request finally went through and I received a response.

I found the solution here: [How to verify recaptcha in node js server call](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-verify-recaptcha-in-node-js-server-call/).

I am hoping others who are having this issue finds this helpful.